How to match very very fuzzy records using either AI models or Machine Learning
I have 2 datasets. One contains transaction records (let's call it transactions_records) obtained via an open_banking solution and invoice line items (let's call it invoice_items) from my own system.
Here is how each dataset look
transaction_records



transaction_id
description
amount
meta




e2751af3-b1cf-42c4-83ed-744azcdz16d695
Gerald MadeUpName payment for my grandson's birthday card
9000
{"timestamp": "2024-03-29T00:00:00Z", "transaction_type": "Credit", "transaction_category": "CREDIT", "provider_transaction_id": null, "transaction_classification": "[]", "normalised_provider_transaction_id": null}


idOfTransaction
"description containing names (Always the last name but sometimes first name or initial of firstname) and a custom message added by the payer"
amountOfTransactionInCents
{"timestamp": "timestamp", "transaction_type": "Credit", "transaction_category": "CREDIT", "provider_transaction_id": null, "transaction_classification": "[]", "normalised_provider_transaction_id": null}



In the meta column, I'm getting the actual date the transaction was made.
invoice_items



invoice_id
due_date
amount
status
full_name
summary




a54a72b6-d9dc-497b-a029-9azcfz30c46f934a
2024-03-31
9000
Overdue
Gerald MadeUpName
Birthday Card ID 1234


idOfInvoiceLineItem
dueDate
amountInvoice
invoiceStatus
fullNameOfPayer
productDescription



note: I have manually matched some invoice_items with the transaction_records in a failed attempts to train a model.
it's basically the transaction_records table with an extra column containing the invoice_id



transaction_id
description
amount
meta
invoice_id




e2751af3-b1cf-42c4-83ed-744azcdz16d695
Gerald MadeUpName payment for my grandson's birthday card
9000
{"timestamp": "2024-03-29T00:00:00Z", "transaction_type": "Credit", "transaction_category": "CREDIT", "provider_transaction_id": null, "transaction_classification": "[]", "normalised_provider_transaction_id": null}
a54a72b6-d9dc-497b-a029-9azcfz30c46f934a


idOfTransaction
"description containing names (Always the last name but sometimes first name or initial of firstname) and a custom message added by the payer"
amountOfTransactionInCents
{"timestamp": "timestamp", "transaction_type": "Credit", "transaction_category": "CREDIT", "provider_transaction_id": null, "transaction_classification": "[]", "normalised_provider_transaction_id": null}
invoice_id



What am I trying to achieve here?
I'm trying to find a solution to match the records in order to update the status of the invoice_items dataset. The problem is: the only key allowing a potential match would be the amount. We also have some supporting keys such as the full name and description which could be used to increased the matching probability.
I have to mention that although I have a good grasp of python, my knowledge is somewhat limited and would truly appreciate some guidance.
I've tried to use to fuzzy matching libraries & started looking at how I could use AI models from Hugging face (not going to lie here, I'm not there yet) but none of the solutions I checked yield any results.
Would truly appreciate some help here
